# Use loop for change values between columns of SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: r, loops, replace

I have a SpatialLineDataFrame with 5 columns 'a','b','c','d','e'. The second column is full of zeros and I want to change them. More specifically I want the values of  'b' column to be 2 times bigger than values of column 'a',  if values of 'a' columns are less than 5 and the rest of them to be 10. I tried:

```
if ((SpatialLineDataFrame@Data$'a') < 5){
  SpatialLineDataFrame@Data$'b'= SpatialLineDataFrame@Data$'a' *2
}else{
   SpatialLineDataFrame@Data$'b'==10
 }
```

But all I get is the values of column 'a' *2. There are no 10 values where column 'a' is <5. How can I fix this?

Comment: SPDF's in R play nicely with "normal" subsetting syntax & vectorized operations: `spdf$b <- ifelse(spdf$a<5, spdf$a*2, 10)`

Comment: Thank you this is very quick and simple!